# yield scrapy.Request does not return the title

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to `Scrapy` and try to use it to practice crawling the website. However, even I followed the codes provided by the tutorial, it does not return the results. It looks like `yield scrapy.Request` does not work. My codes are as follow:

```
Import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from apple.items import AppleItem

class Apple1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apple'
    allowed_domains = ['appledaily.com']
    start_urls =['http://www.appledaily.com.tw/realtimenews/section/new/']

    def parse(self, response):
        domain = "http://www.appledaily.com.tw"
        res = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
        for news in res.select('.rtddt'):
            yield scrapy.Request(domain + news.select('a')[0]['href'], callback=self.parse_detail)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        res = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
        appleitem = AppleItem()
        appleitem['title'] = res.select('h1')[0].text
        appleitem['content'] = res.select('.trans')[0].text
        appleitem['time'] = res.select('.gggs time')[0].text
        return appleitem
```

It shows that spider was opened and closed but it returns nothing. The version of Python is 3.6. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

**EDIT I**

The crawl log can be reached [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw_AhA0Eo__aUEF5Zl9peWxqWVU).

**EDIT II**

Maybe if I change the codes as below will make the issue clearer:

```
Import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Apple1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apple'
    allowed_domains = ['appledaily.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.appledaily.com.tw/realtimenews/section/new/']

    def parse(self, response):
        domain = "http://www.appledaily.com.tw"
        res = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
        for news in res.select('.rtddt'):
            yield scrapy.Request(domain + news.select('a')[0]['href'], callback=self.parse_detail)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        res = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
        print(res.select('#h1')[0].text)
```

The codes should print out the url and the title separately but it does not return anything.

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Comment: @Granitosaurus, I just add the link to the log file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log states:

> 2017-07-10 19:12:47 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to
>    'www.appledaily.com.tw': http://www.appledaily.com.tw/realtimenews/article/life/201
>   70710/1158177/oBike%E7%A6%81%E5%81%9C%E6%A9%9F%E8%BB%8A%E6%A0%BC%E3%80%80%E6%96%B0%E5%8C%
>   97%E7%81%AB%E9%80%9F%E5%86%8D%E5%85%AC%E5%91%8A6%E5%8D%80%E7%A6%81%E5%81%9C>

Your spider is set to:

```
allowed_domains = ['appledaily.com']
```

So it should probably be:

```
allowed_domains = ['appledaily.com.tw']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't even think it is because of this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the content you are interested in your `parse` method (i.e. list items with class `rtddt`) is generated dynamically -- it can be inspected for example using Chrome, but is not present in HTML source (what Scrapy obtains as a response).

You will have to use something to render the page for Scrapy first. I would recommend [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) together with [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) package.